# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in php 7.2.1

Tags: yii2, php-7.2

`count()`: Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in **php 7.2.1**
using **Yii2**

How to resolve this issue?

```
 public static function findAdminByUsername($username)
{
    $adminUser = static::find()->where(['username' => $username,'userType'=>'ADMIN','user_status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE])->one();
    if(count($adminUser)>0){
        return $adminUser;
    }else{
        return null;
   }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: count() does not support in php 7.2.1.

Comment: if my function returns object, I need to convert it to array or viceversa

Comment: Still it's unclear what you're asking, add some relevant code and describe problem

Comment: where is your code in which you are retrieving the object and then trying to count , add the code relevant to your problem

Comment: edited the question.

Comment: added an answer for you see if it helps

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The thing is you are checking for `count > 1` with using `->one()` which looks odd, looking at your code you want to return `NULL` if there is no record found and if you look into documentation the function [`one()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery#one()-detail) already returns `NULL` if there are no records found so you are adding extra code and it could easily be reduced to

```
public static function findAdminByUsername($username)
{
    return static::find()->where(
        [
            'username' => $username,
            'userType' => 'ADMIN',
            'user_status' => self::STATUS_ACTIVE,
        ]
    )->one();
}
```

Comment: Appropriate one and very well explained. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You are using find()......->one() 
so your query should return just an object  ..  without iteration capabilities.

if you want check if the find() return a value or not  then you could check with isset. find()->one() return null if the query fail.

```
  public static function findAdminByUsername($username)
  {
      $adminUser = static::find()->where(['username' => $username,'userType'=>'ADMIN','user_status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE])->one();
      if( $adminUser !== null ){
          return $adminUser;
      }else{
          return null;
     }
  }
```

if you don't need  others that return the result for find()->..one() you could simply return

```
return static::find()->
  where(['username' => $username,'userType'=>'ADMIN','user_status'=>self::STATUS_ACTIVE])
     ->one();
```

Comment: Never use isset() on plain variables. Use `$adminUser !== null` instead. At which point it also becomes obvious that the check is entirely useless in this case, as you just end up returning the same value anyway.

Comment: @NikiC  the find()-->one()  in yii2  return an object when a row is found but return null if nothings is found so isset(..) should be correct  ..